# Routing Error--image routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting the following error:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/public/images/download.png" with {:method=>:get}):

Answer (score 0):

This error means that a request is being made for the following URL:

http://YOURSERVER/public/images/download.png

Typically, this correlates to file in your application's home directory of: 
public/public/images/download.png

Note the "public" dir nested within the "public" dir